# Session variables are not able to access in other controllers in asp.net mvc 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my Data Layer class.

```
public class DataLayer
    {
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AUFBKMDBSR1;DataBase=MVCDemo; Integrated Security=True;");

        public bool select(MainModel mmdl)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            con.Open();
            string query = "select count(*) from SystemUsers where UserName='"+mmdl.UserName+"' and Password='"+mmdl.Password+"'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            flag = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
           return flag;
        }
```

This is my controller.

```
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection frm)

        {
            //Creating object of model
                        //Accessing 

            mmdl.UserName = frm["UserName"];
            mmdl.Password = frm["Password"];
            DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
            if(dl.select(mmdl)==true)
            {
                //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = mmdl; ; 
                 Session["UserName"] = mmdl;
                return RedirectToAction("Outlookhome", "Compose");

            }

            return View();
        }
```

this is my other controller where I am not able to access Session["UserName"]

```
 public ActionResult ComposeEmail(FormCollection frm)
        {

            //creating compose class object to access properties in controller
            Compose cmpse = new Compose();
            cmpse.To= frm["To"];
            cmpse.From = Session["UserName"].ToString(); ;       
            cmpse.Subject = frm["Subject"];
            cmpse.DteTme = frm["DteTme"];
            cmpse.Body = frm["Body"];



           // cmpse.Attachement = frm["Attachement"];
            DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
            //calling compose method from datalayer class to insert values into database.
            if(dl.Compose(cmpse)==1)
            {

            }
            return View();
        }
```

cmpse.from returns null value each time. 
I am not able to use session variable in all all controllers. Please help on this...

Comment: Is   if(dl.select(mmdl)==true) returning true?

Comment: Yes. it is returning true. All values are coming except   cmpse.From = Session["UserName"].ToString();

Comment: In Account controller I am getting session variable and i am able to display session variable in view also. But this same session variable i am not able to retrieve or use in other controllers.

Comment: You are putting the view model in the session, try putting the username only

Comment: have you setup sessionTimeout in web.config?

Comment: I am puting object of model in session but this works fine for me. I am able to display session variable in view. Below is my view code.

Comment: @model MyFirstApp.Models.Compose

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Session["UserName"];
    
}

<h2>Outlookhome</h2>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @{
            var UserName = (MyFirstApp.Models.MainModel)Session["UserName"];
            
        }

         Logined as :- @UserName.UserName;
         </div>
</body>
</html>



@Html.ActionLink("Compose", "ComposeEmail", "Compose")
@Html.ActionLink("Inbox", "Inbox", "Inbox")

Comment: All i nedd to access that session variable in all other controllers.

Comment: No i dint put session timeout in web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reassign back to mmdl where mmdl is the object of your model class

```
    //creating compose class object to access properties in controller
    Compose cmpse = new Compose();
    cmpse.To= frm["To"];

    // assign back to mmdl object
    var mmdl  = Session["UserName"] as your model Class   

    cmpse.From = mmdl.UserName

    cmpse.Subject = frm["Subject"];
    cmpse.DteTme = frm["DteTme"];
    cmpse.Body = frm["Body"];



   // cmpse.Attachement = frm["Attachement"];
    DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
    //calling compose method from datalayer class to insert values into database.
    if(dl.Compose(cmpse)==1)
    {

    }
    return View();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine now. From morning  i was struggling to get answer.

Comment: @Niranjangodbole please make it accepted answer if it solves your problem